# How to send REST call in WSO2ESB with "Date" transport header

Tags: rest, wso2-esb

I'm trying to call a REST service from within WSO2ESB. The request needs to contain an authentication code, which will get computed based on some values including the Date transport header, which must also be part of the transport headers.

```
<syn:property name="Date" value="Mi, 1 Mrz 2015 11:00:00 MEZ" scope="transport" />
<syn:property name="X-Auth-Code" value="SomeCodeBasedOnDateHeader" scope="transport" />
<syn:send>
  <syn:endpoint>
    <syn:http uri-template="http://localhost:8280/rest/resourceA/{uri.var.resA}/resourceB/{uri.var.resB}" method="POST" />
  </syn:endpoint>
</syn:send>
```

But when trying to send the request, the Date transport header will get removed by WSO2 ESB (The REST service will not get any Date header). Is there any chance to include the Date Header?

Answer (score 1):

You can preserve the date by adding the following property to 
D:\stack\wso2am-2.1.0\repository\conf\nhttp.properties
D:\stack\wso2am-2.1.0\repository\conf\passthru-http.properties

```
http.headers.preserve=Date
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that thoses headers are removed in both, NIO and Passthrough http transports :

- Connection
- Transfer-Encoding
- Date
- Content-Length
- Keep-Alive
- Server
- User-Agent

You can preserve **Server** and **User-Agent** headers, setting **http.server.preserve=true** or **http.user.agent.preserve=true** in *ESB_HOME/repository/conf/nhttp.properties* or *passthru-http.properties* depending on which transport is configured in axis2, but it looks like there is no property to preserve **Date** header : you may be required to write your own http transport sender and configure your custom class in *ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml* : `<transportSender name="http" class="sss">`